# Generating a subbasis from a Topology

Tags: general-topology

I know that given a subbasis, a topology could be generated by taking all unions of finite intersections of the elements of the subbasis.
I also know that given a topology, one could generate a basis. My question is, is there a way to generate a subbasis when one is given a topology?

Comment: You can consider the topology itself. Or that basis you are referring to.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Then is there more than one way to get a subbasis from a topology?

Comment: At least as many as there are of selecting a basis.

Comment: There is no "easy way" to find a subbase with a special property, e.g. [supercompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercompact_space) spaces have a special subbase wrt open covers. Every compact metric space has such a subbase, but it's not always obvious how to find it.